# Can you have multiple HttpSessionStrategy?

Tags: spring-social, spring-session, spring-social-twitter

I would like to have a header based `HttpSessionStrategy` as listed below however Spring Social seems to want to store the social token on the session.
When it is redirected back to the application no `x-auth-header` is specified so a new session is created and the token is lost.

Can we have still have the `HeaderSessionStrategy` with the `CookieSessionStrategy` as a fallback?

What is the best way to handle this?

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
  return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy(); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you want.
[SmartHttpSessionStrategy](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-state-securing-restful-apis/blob/master/messages-session/src/main/java/sample/session/SmartHttpSessionStrategy.java)

Comment: Yeah I was also looking at MultiHttpSessionStrategy and just having it do both cookies and headers.  The link you gave will work in a either/or scenario if I can define exactly when I want to do which.  Either way its a good find and gives me another option.

Comment: Will this also work when adding WebSockets into the mix?